# Cannot get exact Image size using JavaScript - TinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am using **TinyMCE** editor and If I upload 3.5 MB image through **TinyMCE editor** on validation getting image size as 4.9 MB.

How to get exact image size, please help.

I am using **Blob** to check size.

```
const tinyContent = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
        const byteSize = str => new Blob([str]).size;
        const byteSizeResult = byteSize(tinyContent);

        const errorHTML = `<div class="erro-save-profile">Content should not exceed 4 MB</div>`;

        console.log('byteSizeResult - ', byteSizeResult)
        if(byteSizeResult > 4100000) {
            $(".erro-save-profile").remove();
            $(errorHTML).insertAfter("#editProfileContainer");
            return false;
        }
```

**Expecting: TinyMCE content/images should not exceed 4MB.**